# Learning Booth's Algorithm, I Can't Find the Issue on Final Result

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, binary

I am practicing using Booth's Algorithm to multiply a positive number and a negative number (specifically the problem is $-12 \times 4$). I have included my attempt, but I can't find the issue. If someone can help me out, I'd really appreciate it. Thank you.

[image]